# How does a SQL query transform the data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674053/count-number-of-rows-in-particular-bucket-at-state-level/) and was trying to understand how the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56674133)
given there is actually transforming the data.

**Input Table**

```
+---------+-------+---------------+
| user_id | State | Subscriptions |
+---------+-------+---------------+
|       1 | LA    |             4 |
|       2 | LA    |             4 |
|       3 | LA    |            12 |
|       4 | LA    |            12 |
|       5 | LA    |             8 |
|       6 | LA    |             3 |
|       7 | NY    |            14 |
|       8 | NY    |            15 |
|       9 | NY    |             3 |
|      10 | NY    |             2 |
|      11 | NY    |             4 |
|      12 | NY    |            12 |
|      13 | OH    |             6 |
|      14 | OH    |             8 |
|      15 | OH    |             2 |
|      16 | OH    |             3 |
+---------+-------+---------------+
```

**Output Table**

```
+--------------------+----+----+----+
| Subscription_Range | LA | NY | OH |
+--------------------+----+----+----+
| 1 to 4             |  3 |  3 |  2 |
| 5 to 11            |  1 |  0 |  2 |
| 12 to 15           |  2 |  3 |  0 |
+--------------------+----+----+----+
```

Answer given by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff):

```
 select (case when subscriptions <= 4 then '1 to 4'
                 when subscriptions <= 11 then '5 to 11'
                 when subscriptions <= 15 then '12 to 15'
            end) as subscription_range,
           sum(case when state = 'LA' then 1 else 0 end) as LA,
           sum(case when state = 'NY' then 1 else 0 end) as NY,
           sum(case when state = 'OH' then 1 else 0 end) as OH
    from t
    group by (case when subscriptions <= 4 then '1 to 4'
                   when subscriptions <= 11 then '5 to 11'
                   when subscriptions <= 15 then '12 to 15'
              end)
    order by min(subscriptions);
```

I wanted to understand fundamentally how this query executes.

For example:

1. When the first row is selected will the `Subscriptions` column be checked first? (Since it is the first that is checked with a `case` in the query.)
2. After checking it turns out that it should be assigned `1 to 4`. Now what next?
3. Will the state column be checked? It turns out that it is `LA` but I am not getting how the further execution is happening. I am trying to imagine the table forming before aggregation.

Does SQL operate in a row-wise fashion? As in, each and every row is picked up from the database and the corresponding part of the query is applied to each column? (Like `case` is applied to the `Subscriptions` column in this case.)

Comment: To know what is checked first, and how, would require digging into the source code for the particular database engine you're interested in. I doubt very much that Microsoft is going to give you access to the source code for SQL Server, but perhaps you could pull the source code for one of the many relational database engines which are freely available and start digging. You may find that there is not a simple or universal answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When evaluating the expressions within the `select` clause **prior to aggregation**, you can imagine that the following table would be obtained for the given dataset:

```
+--------------------+-----+----+----+
| subscription_range | LA  | NY | OH |
+--------------------+-----+----+----+
| '1 to 4'           |   1 |  0 |  0 |
| '1 to 4'           |   1 |  0 |  0 |
| '12 to 15'         |   1 |  0 |  0 |
| '12 to 15'         |   1 |  0 |  0 |
| '5 to 11'          |   1 |  0 |  0 |
| '1 to 4'           |   1 |  0 |  0 |
| '12 to 15'         |   0 |  1 |  0 |
| '12 to 15'         |   0 |  1 |  0 |
| '1 to 4'           |   0 |  1 |  0 |
| '1 to 4'           |   0 |  1 |  0 |
| '1 to 4'           |   0 |  1 |  0 |
| '12 to 15'         |   0 |  1 |  0 |
| '5 to 11'          |   0 |  0 |  1 |
| '5 to 11'          |   0 |  0 |  1 |
| '1 to 4'           |   0 |  0 |  1 |
| '1 to 4'           |   0 |  0 |  1 |
+--------------------+-----+----+----+
```

Here, for each row in the dataset, the first `case` statement yields a string, and the subsequent `case` statements yield either a `1` or `0` depending on whether the `state` column validates the test expression.

When aggregated, the query calculates the same set of `subscription_range` values and  `groups by` this data such that each `subscription_range` is distinct.

The remaining numerical data in the subsequent columns is then summed over each group by the `sum` expressions enclosing each `case` statement, yielding:

```
+--------------------+----+----+----+
| subscription_range | LA | NY | OH |
+--------------------+----+----+----+
| 1 to 4             |  3 |  3 |  2 |
| 5 to 11            |  1 |  0 |  2 |
| 12 to 15           |  2 |  3 |  0 |
+--------------------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort took to write the answer in detailed fashion !!

Answer (score 1):

The first  part case when subscriptions just produce the value for range  alias the keys  used for group  by 
the 3 parts as LA, NY, OH 
use a fake aggregation function for mimic a pivot table

without the fake aggregation function each value is placed in a differente rows ..  the use of group by reduce all the rows with same range to a single rows  .. obtaining so the desired  aspected

```
 select (case when subscriptions <= 4 then '1 to 4'
             when subscriptions <= 11 then '5 to 11'
             when subscriptions <= 15 then '12 to 15'
        end) as subscription_range,
       sum(case when state = 'LA' then 1 else 0 end) as LA,
       sum(case when state = 'NY' then 1 else 0 end) as NY,
       sum(case when state = 'OH' then 1 else 0 end) as OH
from t
group by (case when subscriptions <= 4 then '1 to 4'
               when subscriptions <= 11 then '5 to 11'
               when subscriptions <= 15 then '12 to 15'
          end)
order by min(subscriptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for the taking time to write the answer